# Silverlight DataVisualization Charting Gradient on StackedBarSeries

Tags: xaml, silverlight, charts

I am using the Silverlight charting control: System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting and I wish to remove the gradient that is on the bar where the color is solid at the bottom and gets lighter towards the top, so what I am looking for is a solid bar and not with a gradient.

I have managed to get the original style from Blend for the chart control and added the following to my own style:

```
<Setter Property="PlotAreaStyle">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush>
                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Transparent"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Can someone please help me as I am new to Silverlight and have spent many hours trying to find a solution, I am using this site as a last resort.

This is the code I am using for the chart control.

```
<charting:Chart Loaded="Loaded" Width="{Binding ElementName=Graph, Path=GraphWidth}" Grid.Column="0"  BorderBrush="Transparent"  x:Name="SummaryGraph"
                                Style="{StaticResource SummaryGraphStyle}" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

    <charting:ColumnSeries>
        <charting:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
            <Style TargetType="charting:ColumnDataPoint">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
            </Style>
        </charting:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
    </charting:ColumnSeries>

    <charting:Chart.Axes>
        <DataVisualization:LinearAxisWithAxisLine AxisLabelStyle="{StaticResource YAxisLabel}" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="Bold" Title="{Binding ElementName=Graph, Path=YAxisTitle}" Orientation="Y" />
        <charting:CategoryAxis AxisLabelStyle="{StaticResource XAxisLabel}" FontSize="{Binding ElementName=Graph, Path=XAxisLabelFontSize}" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Orientation="X" />
    </charting:Chart.Axes>

</charting:Chart>
```

Many Thanks,

I am now using this code with the style provided:

```
<charting:Chart Loaded="Loaded" Width="{Binding ElementName=Graph, Path=GraphWidth}" Grid.Column="0"  BorderBrush="Transparent"  x:Name="SummaryGraph"
                                Style="{StaticResource SummaryGraphStyle}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

        <!--<charting:ColumnSeries DataPointStyle="{StaticResource ColumnDataPointNoGradientStyle}" />

    <charting:ColumnSeries>
        <charting:ColumnDataPoint Style="{StaticResource ColumnDataPointNoGradientStyle}"></charting:ColumnDataPoint>
    </charting:ColumnSeries>-->

    <charting:StackedColumnSeries>
        <charting:SeriesDefinition DataPointStyle="{StaticResource ColumnDataPointNoGradientStyle}"/>
    </charting:StackedColumnSeries>

    <charting:Chart.Axes>
        <DataVisualization:LinearAxisWithAxisLine AxisLabelStyle="{StaticResource YAxisLabel}" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="Bold" Title="{Binding ElementName=Graph, Path=YAxisTitle}" Orientation="Y" />
        <charting:CategoryAxis AxisLabelStyle="{StaticResource XAxisLabel}" FontSize="{Binding ElementName=Graph, Path=XAxisLabelFontSize}" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Orientation="X" >
        </charting:CategoryAxis>
    </charting:Chart.Axes>

</charting:Chart>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the DataPointStyle Background on the ColumnSeries. Try setting the style directly into the StackedColumnSeries

`xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit`"

```
   <toolkit:Chart>
    <toolkit:ColumnSeries Title="{Binding ...}" ItemsSource="{Binding ...}" IndependentValuePath="..." DependentValuePath="...">
       <toolkit:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
      <Style x:Key="ColumnDataPointNoGradientStyle" TargetType="toolkit:ColumnDataPoint">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:ColumnDataPoint">
                    <Border x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Opacity="0">
                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding FormattedDependentValue}"/>
                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverHighlight"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionHighlight"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="RevealStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Shown">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Root"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Hidden">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Root"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Rectangle Visibility="Collapsed">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#77ffffff" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#00ffffff" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <Border BorderBrush="#ccffffff" BorderThickness="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                <Border BorderBrush="#77ffffff" BorderThickness="1"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionHighlight" Fill="Red" Opacity="0"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="MouseOverHighlight" Fill="White" Opacity="0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
       </toolkit:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
    </toolkit:ColumnSeries>
   <toolkit:Chart>
```

Here is the full DataPointStyle. The only modification is adding a visibility collapsed to the gradient rectangle: `<Rectangle Visibility="Collapsed">` (located near the bottom)

Comment: Hi Aducci, I have added a snippet above showing how I am attempting to override the ColumnDataPoint, it still doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: @PaulHayes - I added the full style, let me know if you encounter any problems

Comment: thanks for that, I am a bit stuck now, where would I assign the style from which element, for example I have under charting:chart -> charting:columnseries -> charting:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle and I am putting the style here instead of referring to it as a StaticResource

Comment: I am using this under chart object, but still no luck. <charting:ColumnSeries DataPointStyle="{StaticResource ColumnDataPointNoGradientStyle}" />

Comment: btw: I am using a stackedColumnSeries

Comment: @PaulHayes Is the ColumnDataPointNoGradientStyle working at all? You can test by removing other parts or changing value

Comment: @PaulHayes strange, is it possible to try using a regular columnseries? Maybe the StackedColumnSeries is behaving differnetly

Comment: As far as you are aware is it really possible to remove the gradient from the bar?

Comment: @PaulHayes - Yes it is just a style. Something is wrong with your setup, not sure how to help. SOrry